# Is it possible to trigger tooltip in highchart of a line chart ONLY when the mouse hovers over the point?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The default behavior is that the tooltip of the point closest to the mouse will appear whenever the mouse enter the chart area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be difficult to achieve in a line chart - you would need to manually calculate if the mouse position is exactly over the point and depending on this displaying a tooltip or not.

However, you can mock a line chart with a scatter chart with `lineWidth > 0`. Disable sticky tracking and it results with what you are looking for.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        lineWidth: 1,
        stickyTracking: false,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

#### Live example

http://jsfiddle.net/6yc6jn5w/

Comment: I just tried it without mocking it as a scatter chart, it works fine. Did I understand it wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that a line chart with disabled sticky tracking shows a tooltip only when is over a point? http://jsfiddle.net/6yc6jn5w/2/ It seems that it shows a tooltip everytime you are over the line, not only a point.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Another question: I would like the resulting scatter graph to appear as line-like as possible. However, when I make the marker smaller, it is harder to hover over the marker to display the tooltip. Is there anyway around it? (such as making the marker invisible while maintaining its function (btw. set "enable" to false does not work))

Comment: marker.fillColor set to 'transparent' should be able to track the event while the marker remains invisible, you can control its size by marker.radius http://jsfiddle.net/24Lu4ws1/

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the marker such that if the mouse hovers over the marker, there is no other reactions from the markers except for the tooltips (i.e. no half-transparent circles appearing around the markers)?